# WPF UserControl Populate Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

When (what event) should the controls (Combos, Drop-Downs) be populated in a WPF User Control?

Currently I'm using UserControl_Loaded, but this fires more than once, and on a development machine, produces inconsistent results.

```
public UserControl_Load(x, x)
{
   if(!this.Loaded)
   {
     //populate controls here
   } 
}
```

If this is the best practice, then I will try resolve that problem; but I'm more interested in when (what event) is best used for populating controls?

Thanks

> Given Sheridan's answer, I found this wonderful blog post for those who may be looking a great tutorial on how to correctly databind in WPF ([Blog](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/04/05/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-one.html))

Comment: Let WPF decide. Create a view model for your UserControl and bind the child controls to view model properties. The controls will be populated when the bindings are executed.

Comment: Best practice is what @Clemens wrote above, but your approach should work as well.

Comment: Don't manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Create a proper ViewModel and use DataBinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than handling events to populate your controls, try the data binding way instead:

First create a collection property in a class (view model) that implements the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx):

```
// You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface properly here
public ObservableCollection<YourDataType> Items { get; set; }
```

Then you can fill it from code called in the constuctor, or in a `Command` handler in response to some UI action:

```
Items = GetSomeItems();
```

Now, if you have defined a `Binding` for this property to a UI collection control, then the UI will be automatically updated:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    ...
</ListBox>
```

As long as you set the `DataContext` property of the view to an instance of your view model:

```
DataContext = new SomeViewModel();
```

Finally, I'd advise you to take a look at the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for further information.